# Macro pasting on next available row

Tags: excel, vba, pasting

I have a macro copying data from one spreadsheet and I want to paste it to the next available row in a master spreadsheet. However, it is pasting over the last row that I populated. 
Currently on row 620, I want it to paste on row 621 and then next time I run macro, row 622 and so on

In 2019, I will begin at row 3 on new spreadsheet.

```
Sub Paste()
'
' Paste Macro
'

'
    Range("B24:AQ24").Select
    Selection.copy
    Windows("Sales  - 2018.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Range("B620").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        True, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "Invoice Company B Limited Partnership.xlsx" _
        ).Activate
End Sub
```

Not sure how to define next available row in the code.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please read [how to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1|268.2975).

Comment: You need to use last row +1, there are multiple examples, just do a search for "excel vba last row"

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll do some more research. Thanks for the link, SJR,

Comment: You should start here: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Appreciate it, TinMan, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always `B24:AQ24` that you're copying?

This will copy the range and paste onto the next blank row (based on data in column B) in 
`Sheet2` of `Sales - 2018.xlsx`.

It's a single line of code with a line continuation ( `_` ) at the end of the first line.

```
Public Sub Paste()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B24:AQ24").Copy _
        Workbooks("Sales - 2018.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

To begin on row 3 just add a heading into cell `B2`.

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook containing the code.
You may want to change this to `Workbooks("Invoice Company B Limited Partnership.xlsx")` (which doesn't contain any code as it's `xlsx` rather than `xlsm`.)

Comment: Thanks Darren, works a treat! Thanks for taking the time.